# Getting image out of sql blob using php

Tags: php, html, sql, blob

Guys i have this code that get the uploaded image data

```
@$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, htmlentities($_FILES['pet_image_button']['name']));
@$temp = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, file_get_contents($_FILES['pet_image_button']['tmp_name']));
@$imageSize = getimagesize($_FILES['pet_image_button']['tmp_name']);
```

and this query to insert into my database

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES(
                    '',
                    '$temp'
                )";
```

now im trying to get one image and echo it so i used

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" width="290" height="290">'
 . '</dd>';
```

and it show the image perfectly but this way is fast and professional ?
also does this way work with all images extensions? 
I have made many searching and couldn't find what I want

Comment: try them all out. `jpeg` only work for JPG's though. You'll need a different encoding for PNG / GIF

Comment: yea thats what i thought too but it worked with png images too!

Comment: ah, well there you go ;-)

Comment: im afraid that it wont work with all user images